# Python Selenium to select "menuitem" from "menubar"

Tags: python, python-2.7, selenium, selenium-webdriver, menuitem

I have a code that clicks a button on a web page, which pops up a `menubar`.  I would like to select a `menuitem` from the choices that appear, and then `click` the `menuitem` (if possible); however, I'm at a roadblock.

Here is the relevant part of the code so far:

```
from selenium import webdriver
driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get('URL')

Btn = driver.find_element_by_id('gwt-debug-BragBar-otherDropDown')
Btn.click()  #this works just fine

MenuItem = driver.find_element_by_id('gwt-uid-463')  #I'm stuck on this line
MenuItem.click()
```

Here is the error it's throwing, based on what I have written:

```
raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element
```

Note: it appears that the `id` for this element changes each time the page loads (which is probably the cause of the error).  I've tried searching for the element by `find_element_by_class_name` as well, but it has a compound class name and I keep getting an error there, too.

Here's the code of the `menubar`:

```
<div class="gux-combo gux-dropdown-c" role="menubar" id="gwt-debug-BragBar-otherMenu">
```

and the `menuitem` I want:

```
<div class="gux-combo-item gux-combo-item-has-child" id="gwt-uid-591" role="menuitem" aria-haspopup="true">text</div>
```

I'm looking for a way to select the `menuitem`.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can [find the element by xpath](http://selenium-python.readthedocs.org/en/latest/locating-elements.html#locating-by-xpath) and check that the `id` attribute *starts with* `gwt-uid-`:

```
menu_item = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//div[starts-with(@id, "gwt-uid-")]')
menu_item.click()
```

You can also apply additional checks if needed, e.g. check `role` attribute as well:

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//div[starts-with(@id, "gwt-uid-") and @role="menuitem"]')
```

Comment: Thanks for the speedy answer, @alecxe!  Tried it and it did the job perfectly.

Answer (score 2):

Try this xpath

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//div[@role='menuitem' and .='text']').click();
```

**It will check for the 'div' element having attribute 'role' as 'menuitem' and having exact text as 'text'.**

Say, there is a menuitem "Lamborghini AvenTaDor" under your menu. So, the code for that will become:

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//div[@role='menuitem' and .='Lamborghini AvenTaDor']').click();
```

Comment: +1 for the idea, @Subh!  This will really help me out in future coding endeavors.